# How to access specific instances of the Rack middlewares?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack

In my Rails 3.2 application I have to call a method on a middleware instance of a certain class type.

I tried to use `Rails.application.middleware` but that doesn't work because it only wraps the middleware *classes* and not their instances.

Right now I'm walking the middleware chain starting from `Rails.application.app` using Ruby's `instance_variable_get` and `is_a?`, but that doesn't feel right, especially because there is no specified way a middleware stores the context. For example `Rack::Cache::Context` stores the next instance in a variable called `@backend` while most others use `@app`.

Is there a better way to find a middleware instance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could have the middleware add itself to the rack environment, as in this example:

```
require 'rack'

class MyMiddleware
  attr_accessor :add_response
  def initialize app
    @app = app
  end
  def call env
    env['my_middleware'] = self # <-- Add self to the rack environment
    response = @app.call(env)
    response.last << @add_response
    response
  end
end

class MyApp
  def call env
    env['my_middleware'].add_response = 'World!' # <-- Access the middleware instance in the app
    [200, {'Content-Type'=>'text/plain'}, ['Hello']]
  end
end

use MyMiddleware
run MyApp.new
```

Comment: It's a middleware from a 3rd party gem, but thanks to Ruby adding that is no problem :)